# How to set the size of textview depends on the length of text in the?

Tags: android, css

I am facing the situation like that:

I have two textviews on the left and right respectively, the left one has fixed content, and the right one has the content which length of content depends on the data getting from the database.

I want the two textviews with the same height so I set the height of two to be wrap_content and use the `getHeight()`and `setHeight()` after the code for setting text to change the height of left one when the height of right one is extended due to long content. As a result, there is still having different height.

Can somebody tell me which part is wrong and suggest some method to change the height of left one depends on the height of right one beside setting a fixed height of two textview?

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bName"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/add_book_review_top_left"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/bName"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/input_bName"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/add_book_review_top_right"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you add the xml of the textViews?

Comment: I have posted on the above

Comment: If you set the height of one of them to match parent it will be always as high as the other since the parent wraps it (as long as you don't add other views)

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

try below code

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/bName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/add_book_review_top_left"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="5dp"
android:text="@string/bName"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: this will only resize it's width